# How correctly import protobuf's files?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

Inside `city.proto` file I want to use (import) protobuf's `.proto` files. In my golang application I use go modules.

**city.proto**:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package proto;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

option go_package = "./proto";

message City {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp create_at = 1;
}
```

When I try to generate code from `city.proto` file it raise such error:

```
google/protobuf/timestamp.proto: File not found.
city.proto:3:1: Import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto" was not found or had errors.
city.proto:25:5: "google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined.
```

I created a `proto` folder in the directory of my gRPC project. The `city.proto` file is located in this folder. I run such command:

```
protoc -I proto/ proto/city.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:proto/city.
```

This command works only in cases when I don't use import in the proto file.

**go version**:

```
go version go1.12.9 windows/amd64
```

**protoc --version**:

```
libprotoc 3.11.4
```

**echo %GOPATH%**:

```
C:\Users\NNogerbek\go
```

Inside that directory I see three folders with such structure:

```
bin
    protoc.exe
    protoc-gen-go.exe
pkg
    mod
        **packages**
src
    google.com
        protobuf
            timestamp.proto
```

I run such command:

```
go list -f "{{ .Path }} {{ .Dir }}" -m github.com/golang/protobuf
```

Command result:

```
github.com/golang/protobuf C:\Users\NNogerbek\go\pkg\mod\github.com\golang\protobuf@v1.4.0
```

Comment: What command did you run to generate your code?

Comment: I created a `proto` folder in the directory of my gRPC project. The `city.proto` file is located in this folder. I run such command: `protoc -I proto/ proto/city.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:proto/city`. This command works in cases when I don't use import in the proto file.

Comment: After numerous attempts, I found a way to generate the code without errors using the following command: `protoc proto/city.proto -I. -I%GOPATH%/src --go_out=:.`. How do you think is it fine to specify the path to the `src` folder in the command?

Comment: I also want to use proto files of the third party implementation [gogo/protobuf](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) in my own proto file. For example `import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";`. It seems like the problem with the visibility of the files has not been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After numerous attempts, I found a way to generate the go code to my gRPC server without errors using the following command:

```
protoc -I. -I%GOPATH%/src --gogofaster_out=plugins=grpc:. proto/city.proto
```

As you can see in the command, I specify the path to the `src` folder where the protobuf's files are located.

Also I used `gogofaster` plugin of [gogoprotobuf](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) package.